Torque/Moab standard outfile date issue
I am experiencing some potential issues with Torque/Moab. The scheduler outputs files with suspicious time stamps on them and does not output standard error files.
I have launched a script on May 27th that terminates without a standard error file. Instead, the scheduler outputs an empty standard output file dated January 12 2086. Here is the output of ls:
total 512
-rw------- 1 satsho ku_00156   0 Jan 12  2086 yacrd.o49985030
-rw-rw-r-- 1 satsho satsho   271 May 27 10:10 yacrd.sh

A second unrelated job also gave me similar behavior.
total 98M
-rw------- 1 satsho ku_00156    0 Sep  5  2055 IQTREE_50p.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 satsho ku_00156  643 May 27 10:09 iqtree.sh

I also ran a test script with a simple echo command just to check if there was something wrong with my scripts. Here is the full test script submitted simply with qsub.
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -W group_list=ku_00156 -A ku_00156
#PBS -N test
#PBS -M my_email@gmail.com
#PBS -m abe
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l mem=100mb
#PBS -l walltime=00:01:00

echo 'TESTING'

I would expect as output test.o$PBS_JOBID with TESTING written to it and test.e$PBS_JOBID as output.
Instead I get just an empty test.o$PBS_JOBID file
total 512
-rw------- 1 satsho ku_00156   0 May 27  2015 test.o50004034
-rw-rw-r-- 1 satsho ku_00156 280 May 27 12:00 test.sh

The behavior is suspicious to me and I can't figure out if the issue is on my end or at the scheduler end. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
